# Natural ways to make a functor adjoint

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Let $F: C \to D$ be a functor between two categories without a right adjoint. What are some natural ways to create a right adjoint for $F$?

Of course, this does not make sense on the nose. One needs to replace the categories by some other categories that are close enough. So the real question is:

Let $F: C \to D$ be a functor between two categories. Can one find another functor $\hat{F}: \hat{C} \to \hat{D}$ such that $\hat{F}$ admits a right-adjoint $\hat{G}$, such that

1. Solely from the data of $\hat{F}$, one can recover the data of $F$. Namely, there is a construction $\tilde{(\cdot)}$ such that $F \sim \tilde{\hat{F}}$, $C \sim \tilde{\hat{C}}$, and $D \sim \tilde{\hat{D}}$.
2. If $F$ admits a right-adjoint $G$ already, then $\tilde{\hat{G}} \sim G$.

It would be even better if $\hat{(\cdot)}$ is a [localization of categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+fractions).

Comment: If your categories are small and [Cauchy-complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category), a natural choice is to take the presheaf construction. (Cauchy-completeness is necessary because $F$ is only recoverable up to Cauchy completion.)

Comment: One would expect this to be formulated as "freely adding a right adjoint", so that there is a square of functors ${\mathcal C}\to{\widehat{\mathcal C}}$ that is universal in some 2-categorical sense, I think "pseudo", ie "up to unique isomorphism. I don't think this can be achieved by localisation. If $\mathcal C$ is to be *included* in ${\widehat{\mathcal C}}$, whilst the latter also has values for the right adjoint, then ${\widehat{\mathcal C}}$ would have *more objects* than $\mathcal C$, whereas localisation is essentially surjective.

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit too long to be a comment, but hopefully it can shed light on your question.

### Adjointness via representability

The concept of adjointness, like many others in category theory, can be understood in terms of representable functors.

For any functor $\mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{F} \mathcal{D}$, we can define a functor
\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathcal{D} &\xrightarrow{G^{\mathsf{formal}}} &&[\mathcal{C}^{\mathop{op}}, \mathbf{Set}] \\
d &\longmapsto &&(c \mapsto \mathcal{D}(F c, d)).
\end{alignat}

This looks a bit like the Yoneda embedding of $\mathcal{D}$, except its target is the presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$ which first applies $F$ and then takes the Hom functor in $\mathcal{D}$ fixed in its second argument.

Now we can claim the following.

**Proposition.** $F$ has a right adjoint if and only if $G^{\mathsf{formal}} (d)$ is representable for every object $d$ of $\mathcal{D}$.

For the forwards direction, assuming that $F \dashv G$, we get the representability of any functor in the image of $G^{\mathsf{formal}}$ by the natural bijection $\mathcal{D} (F c, d) \cong \mathcal{C} (c, G d)$.
For the reverse direction, define the right adjoint to $F$ to be $Y^{-1} \circ G^{\mathsf{formal}}$ where $Y^{-1}$ is the inverse to the Yoneda embedding defined only on the *representable* functors $[\mathcal{C}^{\mathop{op}}, \mathbf{Set}]$ (every such one is in the essential image of $Y$). Then deduce
$$
\mathcal{C}(c, Y^{-1} G^{\mathsf{formal}} d) \cong [\mathcal{C}^{\mathop{op}}, \mathbf{Set}](Y c, G^{\mathsf{formal}} d) \cong G^{\mathsf{formal}} d (c) = \mathcal{D} (F c, d),
$$
naturally in $c$ and $d$, where the first step uses the adjoint equivalence $Y \dashv Y^{-1}$ and the second step is the Yoneda lemma.

This means that the right adjoint $G$ is a universal solution to the equation $\mathcal{D} \xrightarrow{G} \mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{Y} [\mathcal{C}^{\mathop{op}}, \mathbf{Set}] \cong \mathcal{D} \xrightarrow{G^{\mathsf{formal}}} [\mathcal{C}^{\mathop{op}}, \mathbf{Set}]$.
The formal right adjoint to $F$, $G^{\mathsf{formal}}$, always exists, and it tells you how to build the $G$ under certain conditions.

#### A tangent on profunctors

If you like, you can see $G^{\mathsf{formal}}$ as a profunctor by uncurrying, and this leads to the (slightly disingenuous) slogan:

> Every functor has a right adjoint, but it is a profunctor instead of a functor.

Now, up to Cauchy-completeness, every profunctor which admits a right adjoint in $\mathbf{Prof}$ is equivalent to a functor; analogously, the profunctor obtained from $G^{\mathsf{formal}}$ is equivalent to some functor $G$ exactly when it is a right-adjoint profunctor. This leads to an enhanced slogan:

> Every functor has a right adjoint, but **sometimes** it is profunctor instead of a functor.

In this case, 'sometimes' means that it does not have a right adjoint in the usual sense.

Comment: Christian Lair's group at Paris VII (later Diderot and now Paris Cite') did this kind of thing in the 1980s, somewhere in their journal [*Diagrammes*](http://www.numdam.org/journals/DIA/). @varkor might have the citation; your Answer is an explanation of his Comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'll address the dual question, about functors without a *left* adjoint.

Let $G: D \to C$ be a functor that doesn't necessarily have a left adjoint. Under fairly mild conditions, $G$ has a codensity monad $T^G$. This is a monad on $C$, and it's what you think it is in the case where $G$ *does* have a left adjoint. The slick way to define $T^G$ is as the right Kan extension of $G$ along itself.

The forgetful functor $U^G: C^{T^G} \to C$ (where the domain is the category of $T^G$-algebras) is the universal monadic functor generated by $G$. A bit more precisely, there is a canonical comparison functor $D \to C^{T^G}$, and this exhibits $U^G: C^{T^G} \to C$ as the initial monadic functor into $C$ equipped with a map from $G: D \to C$ in the slice category $\mathbf{CAT}/C$. Draw a triangle to see what I mean!

What this construction does is replace your original functor $G$ by a functor $U^G$ that not only has a left adjoint but is also monadic, in a universal way. So that's more than you asked for. But perhaps it's relevant to your situation.

Of course, there's a dual construction for right adjoints, involving density comonads.

A reference: my paper [Codensity and the ultrafilter monad](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/28/13/28-13abs.html), *Theory and Applications of Categories* 28 (2013), no. 13, 332-370.